# How to display sum of disctinct items in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I would like to display sum all the distinct categories of the products that belongs to the user. I searched on the web, but all the things that I tried doensn't work. You may find the models,view and template below. It doesn't give me anything at the html.

Model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
user       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='products')
category   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
brand      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
product    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
price      = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=100)

class Comp_Product(models.Model):

product     = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comp_products")
competitor  = models.URLField()
price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=100)
change      = models.FloatField()
stock       = models.BooleanField()
last_update = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

View:

```
class DashboardList(ListView):

template_name='dashboard_by_user.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(count_category=Count('category',distinct=True)).aggregate(sum_category=Sum('count_category'))
```

template:

```
   {% for product in product_list %}
     {{product.sum_category}}
   {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate the count of (distinct) categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow,

I'm assuming that you want to count the number of distinct categories for the given user. This can be done like this:

views.py:

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Product

class DashboardList(ListView):
    template_name = 'dashboard_by_user.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        Products = context['object_list']
        context['distinct_category_count'] = Products.values(
            'category').distinct().count()
        return context
```

dashboard_by_user.html:

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<ul>
{% for product in object_list %}
    <li>{{ product.brand }} - {{ product.product }} - {{ product.category }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No Producs yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<p> Number of distinct categories: {{ distinct_category_count }} </p>
```

This should give you an output similar to this one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works. Now, I would like to display whether product is in stock or not and if there is price change or not(basically count the 'change' field from Comp_Product) from the Comp_Product model. Fields that I want to reach are 'stock' and 'change'. I override the get_context_data, but i gave me KeyError. How can I overcome this?

Comment: please accept the answer if your original question is answered. You should be able to do those things similar to the shown solution. Get those values by making queries, then adding it to the template context and use them in the template file.